# what is the equivalent of ActiveRecord#establish_connection in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, mongoid

Table is a Mongoid model that must dinamically map to different databases/tables

```
# app/models/table.rb
class Table
  include Mongoid::Document
end

# in app/controllers/some_controller.rb
def index
   Table.connection.database = :other_database # <- How to do this ???
   Table.table_name = params[:id] # <- How to do this ???
   @records = Table.all
end
```

I want the Table class to:

1. be configured per-request to different databases (on the same mongodb server connection) depending on the current logged in user
2. same for table name

**EDIT**
I know about:

```
 Mongoid.configure do |config|
   name = "control_development"
   host = "localhost"
   config.master = Mongo::Connection.new.db(name)
   config.slaves = [
  Mongo::Connection.new(host, 27018, :slave_ok => true).db(name)
   ]
   config.persist_in_safe_mode = false
 end
```

BUT, does it work for certain models (?) :

```
  # like this i mean
  class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  configure do |config| # configure only this model's connection
    name = "other_control_development"
    host = "localhost"
    config.master = Mongo::Connection.new.db(name)
    config.slaves = [
            Mongo::Connection.new(host, 27018, :slave_ok => true).db(name)
    ]
    config.persist_in_safe_mode = false
  end

 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to multiple databases using this.

Sample config:
https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/spec/config/mongoid_with_multiple_mongos.yml

In your model:

```
set_database :secondary
```

You cannot currently swap databases at runtime the way you want to. This is on the todo list though so keep an eye on it.

Comment: unfortunately the file you linked to no longer exists, which somewhat invalidates this comment. :/

Comment: Not the OP, but I'm guessing this is the new location for the linked file: https://github.com/Tickaroo/mongoid2/blob/master/spec/config/mongoid_with_multiple_mongos.yml